# How can other creatures cast last judgment?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, cleric, spell-components

The 8th-level Sor/Wiz spell *last judgment* [necro] (*Book of Exalted Deeds* 102) has the component celestial, meaning that "[t]he caster must be an outsider with the good subtype to cast this spell" (89).

What's the cheapest, easiest, and most convenient way to meet this component's requirement *without* constantly actually being an outsider with the good subtype?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more? Do you have problems understanding the spell, or do you have a certain character in mind that's looking for a way to cast it?

Comment: I edited your question. I hope it's still asking what you want to ask. If not, feel free to edit it further.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way for a non-outsider non-good-subtype cleric to cast the 8th-level Sor/Wiz spell *last judgment* [necro] (*Book of Exalted Deeds* 102) is likely by first casting the 4th-level Clr spell ***lesser holy transformation*** [trans] (*Spell Compendium* 116) that for 1 round/level changes the caster into a  protectar (*Miniatures Handbook* 66) and, in addition to other effects, the caster's "creature type changes to outsider (good)."

Other methods—like levels in a prestige class that changes the potential caster's type and subtypes like 5 levels of divine disciple (*Player's Guide to Faerûn* 51-2) or 10 levels (and no spellcasting!) of incandescent champion (*Magic of Incarnum* 115-21), or, instead, just wholesale *becoming* a bariaur (*Book of Exalted Deeds* 165-7) using the Ritual of Vitality (*Savage Species* 150)—are usually changes persisting forever. Other spells *can* temporarily change the subject's type to outsider but don't add the subtype good.

For a non-outsider wizard or sorcerer lacking the good subtype, creating or commissioning a custom ***staff of last judgment*** (*DMG* 287) (300 gp +1,800 gp/charge; 4 lbs.) is likely the easiest way to cast the spell, the spell's components *probably* subsumed in the staff's creation. Ask first, though, as a DM may rule that a creature wishing to cast the spell *last judgment* from a staff must still be an outsider with the good subtype, the effects of the celestial component on magic items being, of course, unmentioned by the *Dungeon Master's Guide*. (Instead, in a pinch, a *scroll of last judgment* could be used (it also needing DM approval regarding the spell's unusual component), but the reader uses the scroll's likely (*ahem*) abysmal saving throw DC instead of the reader's own ability scores as one does with a magic staff.)

Comment: Also, is it legit to use Use Magic Device with a scroll?

Comment: @DanB Sure. It's just more complicated than a wizard using a staff *and* saddles the reader with the limitations inherent in the scroll. Feel free to ask another question; employing Use Magic Device to cast a spell from a scroll is messy.

Answer (score 0):

Hey I Can Chan's answer is excellent and I won't repeat his suggestions.
I would like to add:

- if you get the spell on a scroll (or, presumably, a custom staff?), you [may](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/90738/can-you-use-use-magic-device-to-negate-the-celestial-spell-component/90740#90740) be able to use Use Magic Device to emulate the "good outsider" quality.
- if you can cast ninth-level spells, [miracle](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/miracle.htm) can duplicate the effect of "any cleric spell of 8th level or lower" without paying an XP cost.

Answer (score -1):

The Spell is available to anyone that is able to cast spells of level 8 from the following lists: Cleric, Sorcerer, Wizard, Wrath (Book of Exalted Deeds).

The Celestial keyword demands a caster to be a good outsider. To be a good outsider, you'd need to have the correct creature type. Aasimar is a race that is "LG Outsider (native)", so simply being an Aasimar would suffice.

Also, a lvl 20, LG monk that somehow has access to lvl 8 sorcerer, cleric or wizard spells could cast it, as a lvl 20 Monk is considered an outsider.

Comment: The aasimar lacks the [good subtype](http://www.systemreferencedocuments.org/resources/systems/pennpaper/dnd35/soveliorsage/monsterTypes.html#good), and the monk's special ability perfect self doesn't add any subtypes to the monk.