# Can you use Use Magic Device to negate the "Celestial" spell component?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spell-components

In [How can other creatures cast last judgment?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/90722/how-can-other-creatures-cast-last-judgment/90729) we discussed the "Celestial" spell component, which imposes a requirement: "[t]he caster must be an outsider with the good subtype to cast this spell" (Book of Exalted Deeds page 89, apparently).

Activating a scroll requires "no material components or focus".  Does this negate the "Celestial" spell component?

The Use Magic Device skill allows you to ignore various requirements for activating magic items such as scrolls.  In particular, a DC25 check lets you "emulate a race" when using a magic item.  With a successful DC25 Use Magic Device check, can you emulate a good outsider race such as a hound archon?  Does this allow you to activate a scroll of *last judgment* without having the outsider type and good subtype?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the BoED, Celestial is a "special component", and not listed as a material or focus component, so, **no, a scroll would not negate the requirement**.

There is no mention otherwise, but since a race is more specific than a type and a subtype, **it is reasonable to rule "emulate a race" would allow you to emulate a type and subtype**.

Comment: I thought so initially as well, but I couldn't find a race that could be emulated that fit those requirements.

Comment: @Thorborn762 how about hound archons? They have ecl scores and can be PCs so I assume you can emulate them.

Comment: @DanB Wow, I completely overlooked the Hound Archon, it would definitely fit the criteria

Comment: Using logic & reality *(which doesn't necessarily apply to D&D)* reading a scroll *is* a 2-handed task. Hold it by top & bottom (or sides, depending which way it's rolled/written), otherwise it'll either roll up or flap about.